# Como ejecutar un procedure en una Vista ? SQL Server 2012

Tags: oracle, stored-procedure, plsql, sql-server-2012

En mi `Procedure` se ejecuta una **query dinámica** (utiliza `PIVOT`) donde las últimas columnas son dinámicas, por lo tanto cuando quiero crear la vista he probado utilizar `Openquery` y `OPENROWSET` pero siempre muestra el mismo mensaje.

> No puede reconocer los metadatos y se necesita utilizar `WITH RESULT
>   SETS` en el procedure.
>
> Utilizar esto ultimo no es posible ya que las columnas pueden variar.

¿Alguna idea ?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué no conviertes tu Store en una Funcion tipo Tabla?

Comment: te refieres a que transforme mi Store en una función y que devuelva una tabla? tengo entendido que retornar una tabla en una función también se ha de declarar las columnas.

Comment: Declaras la tabla a retornar. el Select que devuelve tu store, declara una tabla con los mismos campos. Crea la funcion y llena esa tabla, al hacer la consulta puedes realizar el select sobre la funcion directamente.

Comment: gracias Angel por contestar. Pero los campos pueden variar, un día podrán ser 3 otro día 6.